# Add # hashtag before parameters in URL

Tags: url, parameters, seo, hashtag

I'm creating a dynamic website which is displaying many products. **There are also filters** like price (from - to), year (from-to) etc. I need to put # symbol before the filter parameters in URL because of Googlebot indexing. But I have no idea how to do it and found no documentation on the internet.

I think it could be done with AJAX script but I don't know where to start.

The question is:
**How do I insert a # hash symbol before parameters in URL?**

I've got this:

```
http://domain.com/pd/?rps=100&a=2001
```

and I need to make it look like

```
http://domain.com/pd/#rps=100&a=2001
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to replace the "?" with "#". For well optimised url to seo, you can leave them unchanged. You can also use Google Webmaster Tool to declare your url parameters. Here is another resource for you to optimize your url :[Faceted navigation](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/02/faceted-navigation-best-and-5-of-worst.html)